# Are the dialogs at Sophia's (the robot) appearings scripted?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, robotics, robots, sophia

I talk about the robot from: [Hanson Robotics](http://www.hansonrobotics.com/robot/sophia/), which was [granted the right to citizenship from Saudi Arabia](https://techcrunch.com/2017/10/26/saudi-arabia-robot-citizen-sophia/).

I have found the following articles:

## Your new friend is a humanoid robot

Source: [theaustralian.com.au](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/life/say-hello-to-your-new-friend-sophia-the-humanoid-robot/news-story/070299a8d11b7d636848f1b8dd753530)

> Like Amazon Echo, Google Assistant and Siri, **Sophia can ask and answer questions about discrete pieces of information**, such as what types of movies and songs she likes, the weather and whether robots should exterminate humans.
>
> But her general knowledge is behind these players and she doesn’t do maths. **Her answers are mostly scripted** and, it seems, from my observation, her answer are derived from algorithmically crunching the language you use.
>
> Sometimes answers are close to the topic of the question, but off beam. Sometimes she just changes the subject and asks you a question instead.
>
> She has no artificial notion of self. **She can’t say where she was yesterday, whether she remembers you from before**, and doesn’t seem to amass data of past interactions with you that can form the basis of an ongoing association.
>
> Questions such as: *“What have you seen in Australia?”*, *“Where were you yesterday?”*, *“Who did you meet last week?”* and *“Do you like Australia?”* are beyond her.

---

## Why Sophia the robot is not what it seems

Source: [smh.com.au](http://www.smh.com.au/comment/why-sophia-the-robot-is-not-what-it-seems-20171030-gzbi3p.html)

> You can often fool this sort of software by introducing noise. That could be literal noise – machines aren't great at filtering out background noise, as anyone with a hearing aid will tell you – or it could be noise in the sense of irrelevant information or limited context. You could ask **"what do you think of humans?"** and then follow up with **"can you tell more about it?"** The second question requires the robot to define "it", remember what it said last time, and come up with something new.
>
> In the case of the ABC interview, **the questions were sent to Sophia's team ahead of time so they were possibly pre-scripted**. Just like an interview with a human celebrity!

---

## Pretending to give a robot citizenship helps no one

Source: [theverge.com](https://www.theverge.com/2017/10/30/16552006/robot-rights-citizenship-saudi-arabia-sophia)

> Sophia is essentially a cleverly built puppet designed to exploit our cultural expectations of what a robot looks and sounds like. It can hold a stilted conversation, yes, but its one-liners seem to be prewritten responses to key words. (As Piers Morgan commented during an interview with Sophia, **“Obviously these are programmed answers.”**)

---

Here are a few more references.

- [Inside the mechanical brain of the world’s first robot citizen](https://qz.com/1121547/how-smart-is-the-first-robot-citizen/)
- [Sophia, the Uncanny Robot AI, Is Not What You Think.](https://buildabuddha.quora.com/Sophia-the-Uncanny-Robot-AI-Is-Not-What-You-Think)
- [How much of Robot Sophia’s speech is likely scripted with your understanding of the progress in NLP?](https://www.quora.com/How-much-of-Robot-Sophia%E2%80%99s-speech-is-likely-scripted-with-your-understanding-of-the-progress-in-NLP)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sophia uses [ChatScript](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07791).

You can read about what ChatScript can do [here](https://github.com/ChatScript/ChatScript/blob/master/PDFDOCUMENTATION/OVERVIEWS-AND-TUTORIALS/What-is-ChatScript.pdf).

> ChatScript keeps track of conversations with each user; can record
>   where it is in a conversational flow and what facts it has learned
>   about a user (you have to tell it what facts to try to learn). You can
>   optionally keep logs of the conversations (either on a ChatScript
>   server or locally on a freestanding device).

Comment: Thanks Rebecca! The link you provide talks about the [Loving AI project](http://noetic.org/blog/communications-team/loving-artificial) and I think I've just found another github repo which is quite relevant: [github.com/opencog/loving-ai](https://github.com/opencog/loving-ai). `Sophia` is mentioned several times if one does a [search](https://github.com/opencog/loving-ai/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sophia&type=) in the source code.