# Which algorithm is used in the robot Sophia to understand and answers the questions?

Tags: robotics, robots, question-answering, sophia

Which algorithm is used in the robot Sophia to understand and answer the questions?

Comment: [Here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4375/2444) is a related question, if not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sophia ,first , has all the questions and corresponding answers preprogrammed. It is a system which is a hybrid of Bayes Text classification and decision trees.

- It may consist of a speak recognizer which converts the question into a string.
- This string then travels into a algorithm which gets a suitable answer for it.
- The answer is then spoken by the speech synthesizer along with some face actions.
- It might also have a sentiment analyser which identifies sentiments in a answer to show face expressions accordingly.
- Along with this, it identifies the emotions on the face of the person sitting in front of it, so as to provide a greater expression.

**Hence, Sophia understands or thinks nothing like the human brain. It is just a system which gives predefined answers corresponding to the question asked.**

Comment: This answer does not provide any evidence (links/references) to support what it says.